# Convert pandas dataframe column to numpy array with each separated based on value in otehr column

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns like:

```
data = {'first_column':  [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 11, 12, 13],
        'second_column': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['first_column','second_column'])
```

I want to get a numpy array like follow:

```
array([[[1.1], [2.1], [3.1], [4.1], [5.1], [6.1]], [[0.1], [0.2], [0.3], [0.4]], [[11], [12], [13]]])
```

I´m not able to accomplish getting this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
df.groupby(['second_column']).apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda el:[el], x['first_column'].to_list()))).values
```

I'm grouping by your second column and converting series within each group to lists.

```
list(map(lambda el:[el],...))
```

This part converts each element of a list to an individual list as mentioned by you in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way using aggregate:

```
l = df.groupby("second_column")["first_column"].agg(list).tolist()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [11.0, 12.0, 13.0]]
```